# $('body').offset().top always returns 8 even with nothing else on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset

I was under the impression that `$('body').offset().top` should return `0`, but apparently it keeps returning `8`. I removed all unnecessary code from my webpage and it still returns `8`.

Here is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                console.log($('body').offset().top);
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

That's literally everything in my code. Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lspkx2su/

Comment: Body has a margin of 8 by default, try setting that to 0, or using a css reset.

Comment: An alternative to a reset is normalize.css, which keeps useful settings and makes them consistent across browsers. it's a bit off topic, but worth noting: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default CSS. Insert this:

```
<style>
  html, body { margin: 0 }
</style>
```

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

By default the styling for body tag uses up space in the webpage.

Try this code you'll understand -

The HTML

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
Hello World
</div>
</body>
```

and the following CSS

```
.wrapper{
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

When you run the above code, you'll see that your "Hello World" is displayed with a small offset. This is default in HTML/CSS.

However, @amadan is absolutely right. You should always use the following to start your webpage CSS. No offset problem will occur.

```
body{
  margin:0;padding:0;  
  /* considering your outermost div to be the wrapper of your whole page */
}
```